# Undo scroll bar styling using css

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have theming in my application, so I toggle between themes, which changes the style of scroll bars also. But I lost the default style of the scroll bar. As like in my one theme I remove up and down arrow, and in another, I have to show them.
Can you please explain how to get back those up and down arrow in the scroll bar. 
Like: 
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: Can you please specify what exactly you would like to achieve? Is it intended behaviour that one theme **does have** the scroll bar arrows, and the other theme **should not have** them, or is it vice versa?

Comment: That's correct Spark. One should have one should not have. I am changing dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a value use `initial`.

Something like `height: initial;` should revert to default.

Comment: No it's not possible to revert scrollbar costumization.